# Codeigniter multidimensional language array, issues?

Tags: php, codeigniter, lang

I'm creating a website in CodeIgniter, I wanted to know if this way of using a multidimensional array in the language file would create any problems, like this:

```
$lang['profile']['name'] = 'The text to be shown';
```

This way I can use one file for multiple things and also I can to loop thru buttons this way:

```
$lang['profile_btns']['1'] = 'Text btn 1';
$lang['profile_btns']['2'] = 'Text btn 2';
//Etc...
```

I read the values like this:

```
foreach ($this->lang->line('profile_btns') as $key => $value){
    echo $value;
}
```

This is working fine, but I'm not sure if using this method would/could create any issue due to the non-standard CI use (this is not written in the CI manual).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your codes right except spelling. Use `profile_btns` in foreach instead of `profile_btn`

```
foreach ($this->lang->line('profile_btns') as $key => $value){
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Tks, I fixed that, so basically there are no problems/issue if I use this code!? Good!

Comment: Your approach is used by language library also ;) there are arrays, see yourself. I think this is best way how to load "template text" from config files.